# Makefile: for-loop in a rule inside of a function

Tags: makefile

To make things simple, focus on the following example:

```
define FOO

test:
    @for str in a b c d ; do \
        echo $$str; \
    done;

endef

$(eval $(call FOO))
```

And I suppose when I entered

```
make test
```

I will get

```
a
b
c
d
```

(this is what I get if the rule is not defined in a function)

but unfortunately it gives me

```
tr
tr
tr
tr
```

I want my makefile gives me the previous(correct) result. Please help.

Moreover, I need to work with function to generate make rules.
There have already been many existing rules in the actual makefile and I don't want to take a completely different way to do this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add more escaping, unfortunately.  The end result you want is `$$` in the rule, but the `call` function expands its argument, so you need:

```
define FOO

test:
        @for str in a b c d ; do \
            echo $$$$str; \
        done;

endef

$(eval $(call FOO))
```

There are other alternatives but most depend on the *real* contents of `FOO` which you haven't give us.  For example, if you really don't use any arguments you don't need `call` at all.  You can also look at the `value` function.